# Unable to access to Web API with browser (XML error)

Tags: html, xml, database, azure, unity-game-engine

Good evening,

Recently I have made a simple Web API with Azure Function App + Cosmos DB. So far it worked perfectly (I used Postman to hit the endpoints and everything went fine). However, now I'm trying to access directly to the Web API with the browser https://.azurewebsites.net/api/assets and I found this error that impedes me to access to the page:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<ApiErrorModel xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Models" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Arguments i:nil="true" xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"/>
<ErrorCode>0</ErrorCode>
<ErrorDetails i:nil="true"/>
<Id>c69b0acd-e646-4b09-8dc2-2444b34a177a</Id>
<Message>An error has occurred. For more information, please check the logs for error ID c69b0acd-e646-4b09-8dc2-2444b34a177a</Message>
<RequestId>b1f2d2ed-ec03-4f3e-9482-60d023bb9e79</RequestId>
<StatusCode>InternalServerError</StatusCode>
</ApiErrorModel>
```

Do you know how can I fix this problem?, bear in mind that I'm using the Function App from Azure Microsoft

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the log say for error ID c69b0acd-e646-4b09-8dc2-2444b34a177a?

Comment: Hi, I forgot to mention a detail; in the error, there's a heading that rests: "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it". I also forgot to mention the aim of the REST API: I wanted to access a simple JSON file. And about the error ID, I tried to check it with KUDU and with the monitor of function app, but the error and its ID does not appear either in any place... weird

Comment: 2018-07-12T18:43:20.444 [Error] {"id":"0fe39e31-14b4-449b-ba40-3cad1dd0a8dd","requestId":"d4c3af72-a2a6-45fe-aeb2-524552986c29","statusCode":500,"errorCode":0,"message":"An error has occurred. For more information, please check the logs for error ID 0fe39e31-14b4-449b-ba40-3cad1dd0a8dd"}
2018-07-12T18:43:20.444 [Error] System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException : Type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' is a recursive collection data contract which is not supported. Consider modifying the definition of collection 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' to remove references to itself.

Comment: This is want I found using the log streaming of azure